# JavaScript broken after doctype was added

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

I inherited some pages that uses Java Script to do calculations and draw on graphs on canvas tag.

Their JS pages do not have  `<!DOCTYPE html>`; they only just start with the `<html>` tag.

My site has `<!DOCTYPE html>` and now that I added that code to my site it doesn't work.

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: So it just sits on the couch all day, eating donuts and watching daytime soaps? What does "it doesn't work" mean, as well?

Comment: take a look at http://gexconcom.ipage.com/toold/test.php
If I add a doctype in there the graph that is being drawn for the results no longer works.

I am not sure what to do here at ALL.

Comment: I tried using Iframe now to :include: the older page (no doctype) in the newer page (html 5) and IE 9 converted the child page to have a doctype http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?743000-IE9-Iframes-DOCTYPES-and-You ARG!

Answer (score 4):

That's because your browser is operating in "quirks mode" if there is no DOCTYPE statement right before the <html> tag.

That means whoever wrote the javascript was relying on quirks mode to execute it. Therefore, now that you have a DOCTYPE tag, your browser is operating under a different set of behaviors, as defined by whichever version is specified in the DOCTYPE.

The difference between the two is subtle until your code breaks. I used to never put a DOCTYPE tag until this exact issue came to bite me in the butt.

Comment: The content of the DOCTYPE for pages served by a server is almost always irrelevant. Browsers use the content type in the resopnse header instead (which is why documents with an XHTML DOCTYPE are treated as HTML, because that's what's used in their content type). It is the mere presence or absence of a DOCTYPE that triggers standards or quirks mode.